# Connection to database fails in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a problem that I don't understand. I was working with QGIS and Postgis on importing and exporting layer from and to database, everything was doing very well. Suddenly the connection to the database fails. I'm getting this error message in QGIS:

[image]

What could be the cause and how to solve it?

Comment: In your main connection properties, did you click the 'SAVE' buttons next to the username and password options? I find if these are not clicked, and there is a brief network hiccup or something, QGIS can't automatically re-connect because the u/p were not SAVED.

Comment: I can't even create a new connection to database.

Comment: Can you rule out a server problem? Can you, for example, connect with PgAdmin?

Comment: Maybe need more clues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934364/psql-server-closed-the-connection-unexepectedly

Comment: I did it but still the connection with the database is vain.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS maybe 3 times.

I had some malwares on my computer. I downloaded an anti-malware and I launched the process of detecting them and putting and them in the quarantine.

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled qgis another time and now, every thing works as it used to be.

Comment: Could you be more precise ?

Comment: I had some malwares on my computer which engenders the problem of the of connection with database. When I downloaded an anti-malware and I launched the process of detecting them and putting and them in the quarantine, after that I had just to uninstall and reinstall qgis and every thing start working as it used to be.

Comment: I added your detailed answer :) Maybe the solution was only in your qgis re-install ? Or did you tried that solution already before using the anti-malware ? Just trying to see whether the solution is the malware or the reinstall.

Comment: No the malware was the source of the pb because I uninstall and reinstall it maybe 3 times before I get ride of it.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It's useful to know malware can be the cause :) I updated your answer accordingly. Next time, you can update your answer with any info you have collected to be as precise as possible as this.